# Changing the behavior of a widget type in another class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a MainWindow class in Qt, in which several checkable QGroupBox widgets are placed.

What I want to do is, to trigger a general onClick(bool checked) slot whenever one (**any**) of the QGroupBox objects are clicked, identify the sender and trigger some code.

I need to capture the objects' "clicked" signal in order to prevent a disabling action it performs on its children when the control is clicked.

This is the signal I'm trying to handle:

```
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGroupBox : public QWidget
{
    ...
    Q_SIGNALS:
        void clicked(bool checked = false);
    ...
};
```

I tried adding a custom slot like this and tried connecting it with the signal above but since QGroupBox at its own is not an object or pointer, the operation fails.

```
void MainWindow::onClick(bool clicked)
{
    qDebug()<<"Custom slot triggered";
}
```

Long story short, I need to handle a control type's default behavior within my MainWindow class.

Thanks for any ideas in advance.

Comment: how did you do that "I managed to override a QGroupBox class' setChecked method within my MainWindow.cpp file"?

Comment: I really don't know but I just wrote the method name in my MainWindow class, and when the MainWindow is loaded, the method is triggered once for each QGroupBox I added to the MainWindow.

Comment: you can not override a method of a class by not inheriting that class.

Comment: Then I guess it was a random occasion in which the method is somehow registered to the owner class' signal. It may be something I did elsewhere in the code. But I definitely see 3 triggers if I have 3 group boxes placed in the MainWindow.
Nonetheless, this phenomenon is not very relevant to my actual question, therefore I will remove it to prevent distraction.

Comment: `but since QGroupBox at its own is not an object or pointer` What do you mean by that? `QGroupBox` is derived from `QWidget` (so indirectly also from `QObject`) plus it has the `Q_OBJECT` macro (I looked up the header and it has it, don't know why you have missed it in your quote). Obviously you have to have the instance in order to connect to it. Since the groupboxes are a parent of your window (I presume...) they are its children, so you can access these without any problem and connect their `clicked` signal to the `onClicked` slot of your custom main window.

Comment: Show us more code namely where you create your group boxes and their relation to your main window. The things you have provided in your question should work. There is something else that is missing from the whole picture.

Comment: @rbaleksandar , I'm trying to create a generic connection between any instance of "QGroupBox" created within MainWindow, withOUT explicitly connecting each instance I create. I mean, instead of adding a `connect(groupBoxInstance1,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(onClick(bool)))` line for every GroupBox I add (I may have 200 GroupBoxes in my window), I'm trying to come up with a generalized solution.
This problem should not be thought a specific case with my code, think of it as a Qt problem.

Comment: You can get all children of a given type (for example through `findChildren<...>(...)`) and then automatically connect these ([`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) should also help you to do this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kuba Ober, maybe you're right, I could not state my problem and the facts around it seperately and clearly. Thank you for pointing that out.

After checking out the QGroupBox class' source, I discovered that a "toggle" signal is emitted after every other operation in a "clicked" event.

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qgroupbox.cpp

```
void QGroupBox::setChecked(bool b)
{
    Q_D(QGroupBox);
    if (d->checkable && b != d->checked) {
        update();
        d->checked = b;
        d->_q_setChildrenEnabled(b);
#ifndef QT_NO_ACCESSIBILITY
        QAccessible::State st;
        st.checked = true;
        QAccessibleStateChangeEvent e(this, st);
        QAccessible::updateAccessibility(&e);
#endif
        emit toggled(b);
    }
}
```

By combining this information with that of @rbaleksandar 's suggestion, I managed to obtain a solution.

I iterated through the controls of my MainWindow class and connected every QGroupBox's "toggle" signal with a common "MainWindow::onToggle" slot in which I could handle the post-event operations I desire.

As for my previous approach, I could've created a class which inherits QGroupBox and override any methods I wish to. But that would be overkill compared to my current solution. The fix I've came up with did the trick perfectly.

Thanks everyone for their insight and help.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to capture the objects' "clicked" signal in order to prevent a disabling action it performs on its children when the control is clicked.

Perhaps, but I'm smelling an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. You can certainly prevent emission of signals by invoking `blockSignals()` on the widget. But that's a hack - it will also prevent Qt's internals from acting on the object's `destroyed()` signal, and you might subtly break other users of the object's signals.

Instead, one could make the UI stateful and have the controller implement the stateful aspect of the button's interaction with the rest of the application. Currently, the button's `clicked()` signal is connected directly to other users. Instead, connect the button to the controller, and have the controller disable the children only when it's appropriate to do so. One could use the `QStateMachine` to make this stateful behavior explicit in terms of states.